# Discord.py disable INFO messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

whenever I start my discord.py bot, these INFO messages come up to my screen session. I don't want to be them there. I didn't had this issue back then but somehow it just came up now.
The messages that I'm talking about is this:
[image: My image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the bot simply put `log_handler=None`:

```py
bot.run("TOKEN", log_handler=None)
```

Comment: It worked but It gave me error with ```""``` chars. Just delete them.